# How to make Leaflet maps accessible and WCAG2 compliant

Tags: leaflet, wcag2.0

I have followed several threads on this topic but have not been able to fix the following issues:

1. How to prevent Leaflet map tile images names from being read out by screen readers?
2. How to make vector layers (like Circles and Rectangles) tabbable?
3. How to make tile images not selectable - is this related to #1?

I have tried with current Leaflet distribution 0.7.5 and 1.0 Beta2 - without any success. Here are some related discussions:

[Leaflet issue: accessibility improvements](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/3210)

[StackOverflow: how to make Leaflet tile layers accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745454/how-to-make-leaflet-tile-layers-accessible)

Does anyone have a link to share - to a Leaflet based site/page that is WCAG2 compliant?